# Dynamic font faces from zipped file?

Tags: javascript, css, zip, unzip

After a few hours of attempting this, I'm starting to think it may be more work than it's worth but here goes:

My users are uploading zipped files that include a .woff file. On page load, I need to step through each of these zipped records and use their .woff file as the src for a dynamic @font-face.

So, the end goal would be something like:

```
<style type="text/css">

    {% for font in fonts %}

        @font-face {
            font-family: "{{ font.name }}";
            src: url({{ font.woff_file }});
        }

   {% endfor %}

</style>
```

I started to mess with zip.js but didn't have too much luck and the documentation is pretty limited. How could I do something like this? Is the effort worth it, or should I just force my users to upload a .woff outside of the zipped file (I've done this and it works just fine, of course)

Comment: You need to specify how your users are uploading their files. Presumably you're using a server-side language? If so, then this would be a better route to unzip your files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post sounded interesting because it was joining so many new features so I decided to try it, however next time try to provide more information and a jsfiddle or codepen with your work so far ;).

The great trick is to use data URI this way we can store the font files we unzip from the files and use them in @font-face rules.

Once we get the Entry for the font file we just get it data:

```
fontEntry.getData(new zip.Data64URIWriter(fontMimeType), function(data){ appendFontFace(data, fontType); });
```

and use it to append in a @font-face rule:

```
function appendFontFace(dataUrl, fontType){
    var fontFace = document.createTextNode("\
@font-face {\
    font-family: 'font-name';\
    src: url('" + dataUrl + "') format("+fontType+");\
}\
");

  //remove the previous font-face if any
  if(style.childNodes.length > 0)
    style.removeChild(style.childNodes[0]);

  style.appendChild(fontFace);
}
```

You can check it working in:
http://codepen.io/luizgrs/pen/zAxly

Comment: Your answer definitely solved the problem! I did end up dealing with it server-side instead (felt a little cleaner), but this also did the trick. Thank you!